# Combinatorial summation in C

Tags: c, combinations, cartesian-product, large-data

let us say we have 4 applications which produce 100 data points. So, now we have 400 data points in total.
But if we want to find out what would be the sum of the data points in all these following cases
100*100*100*100. How would you do that?

the 100 datapoints for each application are in the form of an array of type`[a][b]` where `a`and b are 10, 10.

so, for each application it is `[app][a][b]` for a given data point.
and the summation seems pretty simple: `[app][a][b]+[app1][a][b]...`

However, this is where i'm stuck. i don't know how to get the combination of total for example
how would one calculate the sum of combinations of data in `C`...that is, `100*100*100*100`datasets.

I missing some math here. if you can help me here it'd be great.

EDIT:

```
app0 [[17, 24, 85, 43, 4], [92, 6, 17, 62, 20], [72, 100, 59, 84, 67]]
app1 [[83, 8, 95, 74, 61], [95, 84, 15, 70, 89], [6, 91, 13, 85, 43]]
app2 [[88, 98, 86, 52, 32], [37, 1, 96, 43, 72], [10, 62, 76, 100, 35]]

possible data sets are
17+83+88
17+83+98
....
17+83+37
...
```

Comment: Tell me If I'm not clear. I'll make a smaller exampel.

Comment: The first thing you should consider is how the applications output their "data points". Then you have to think about how to import the data into the summation program. Once loaded into the summation program, the rest should be pretty easy.

Comment: Is it only ever going to be 4 applications? Or can there be more?

Comment: they are in floating points, Joachim
Bytefire, there can be more than four applications..

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I know how to do the summation part. that is fairly simple. I fail to get the combination of power data that is, 100*100*100*100.. and what kind of a datastructure could handle it.

Comment: These data are generated at run-time.. so it is not a problem of reading teh output of datapoints.

Comment: Unless you're going to transfer the data between different machines, just write out the matrix in raw binary form to a file. Then the summation program can just read these four files into its own matrices.

Comment: but this data is generated every second...100^4 or 1000^4 into binary everytime? I need this data in run-time to compute something else.

Comment: Then you might want to read about [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) for the data. Though you might have a synchronization problem if the apps creating the data is not perfectly in sync. However, if you have some kind of synchronization between the apps and the summation app, then it should be easy for the summation app to copy the data to local buffers and calculate on that local data.

Comment: Also remember that computers today are *incredibly* fast, and if you use threading or [SSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) instructions, or possibly a combination of both, then handling the amount of data in a timely manner will not be a big problem.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of how to do combinatorial summation with scaling with number of applications and datapoints. 
Then i'll go ahead and try the shared memory one.

Comment: Speaking of SSE instructions.. doesn't gcc 4.8 already have SIMD pragma inbuilt. the assembly atleast tells me that.

Comment: Just FYI, that's not combinations you describe. That's the Cartesian product.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Please also note that the value of a and b can be different.. :)

Comment: @user3808088 Are you looking for the 10x10 table being the sum from all programs?

Comment: @StianV.Svedenborg: Added more information. :)

Comment: And you want the total sum of all those combinations?

Comment: Yes. that's exactly what i want.

Comment: Do you understand that for just four applications, you are talking about computing 300,000,000 floating-point sums per second?  That's probably achievable -- if you intend to simply throw away the results -- but one more app increases it to 40,000,000,000, a.k.a. 40 GFLOPS.  That's gonna be about your limit for a single machine (and even then it probably requires parallelization and/or a dedicated FP unit such as a Tesla).  Of course, if you intend to *do* anything with the results, then the I/O overhead will kill you long before you get close to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about whether I've got this correctly, so correct me if I'm wrong:

You have `X = 4` amount of... *tables*, let's say; and then each table has `Y = 10` amount of *rows*, with each row that has `Z = 10` amount of *columns*. You are to get one element from each of the tables and add them together. Each time you add `X = 4` elements together, one from each table. You want to group these sums, and then add those sums together into a greater/ultimate sum. Am I right?

If so, it means that in the end you'll end up with `(Y * Z) ^ X`, that is `(10 * 10) ^ 4 = 100 000 000` individual sums for the given values, which you are regarding as *combinations* in your question, when they actually are *sums of each combination*. In the end, you want the *sum of sums of each combination*, is this what you're after?

Well then, here's what I'm thinking that may help you out:

```
a[tableindex][rowindex][columnindex]
```

Shall denote the number in a given cell, indexes shall be zero based. While generating the sums of each combination, things will looks as follows:

```
a[0][row0][column0] + a[1][row1][column1] + a[2][row2][column2] + a[3][row3][column3]
```

The table-indexes will remain constant and each one of the row- and column-index will bounce everywhere from `0` to `Y - 1 = 9` for rows and to `Z - 1 = 9` for columns. Now I want to ask you this, how many times will we encounter `a[0][0][0]` as a term?

- `row0` and `column0` will have to be `0`, constant.
- `row1`, `row2` and `row3` will be able to range from `0` to `9`, `Y = 10` possible values.
- `column1`, `column2` and `column3` will be able to range from `0` to `9`, `Z = 10` possible values.

Possibilities get multiplied in maths, `1 * 1 * (10 * 10 * 10) * (10 * 10 * 10) = 1 000 000` is the answer. A general formula for that can be written to it as `(Y * Z) ^ (X - 1)`, `(Y * Z)` because it is the amount of cells in a table, raised to the power of `(X - 1)` because there are that many tables excluding the one we've fixed.

Since each table has same amount of cells, and since this example will hold true for every single term; you can simply add every single cell together, then multiply the result by `(Y * Z) ^ (X - 1)`, which is a million in for your case. Following code would do that, provided that your numbers are small enough to not cause an overflow:

```
#define tablecount 4
#define rowcount 10
#define columncount 10

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int a[tablecount][rowcount][columncount] = { 0 };

    // Assuming it gets filled somewhere in between

    int thenumber = 0;
    for (int table = 0; table < tablecount; table++)
        for (int row = 0; row < rowcount; row++)
            for (int column = 0; column < columncount; column++)
                thenumber += a[table][row][column];

    for (int i = 1; i < tablecount; i++)    // notice that the initial value for i is 1
        thenumber *= rowcount * columncount;

    return 0;
}
```

Make sure to fill the array in-between, and also to include appropriate libraries whenever needed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now that we have the basics down, we can analyse the problem:

> Given T tables of N rows and M columns, what is the total sum of all possible sums using exactly 1 element from each table.

We have the pattern:

```
17+83+88
17+83+98
....
17+83+37
```

Notice that in this pattern, the number 17 from the first loop will be there once for every other combination of the remaining program. But exactly how many?

There will be 100 different occurrences from the second program, and for each of those 100 occurrences from the third, etc.

If you simply reorder the dataset from the different program you will get exactly the same pattern, therefore we can conclude that the sum of all possible combinations = (M*N)^(T-1) * (sum of all elements).

We can write this as a triple for-loop:

```
unsigned int T, N, M; // These are known.

//Assuming the input is of the form
float  data[T][M][N];

long double result = 0.0;

for (int app = 0; app < T; app++) {
    for (int row = 0; row < M; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < N; col++ ) {
            result += data[app][row][col];
        }
    }
}

result *= pow(N*M, T-1);
```

Comment: No, I'm looking at all combinations of data points to be summed up.

Comment: @user3808088 Combinations in which way? The sum of all *products* of elements with exactly one element from each program? The sum of all *sums*? Or something else?

Comment: The total number of datasets will be 15*15*15, right?